# How to select all the TextFields on a FormPanel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

How would I select all the child components of a `FormPanel` that are of the component type `TextField`?

I want to loop through only the `TextField` components and set their values to `""`.

I have this inside a method on a `FormPanel`

```
this.query('textfield').forEach(function(item) { console.log(item.id); } );
```

It selects too much stuff, it selects all the nested `TextFields` inside of `ComboBox` and `DateField` and what not.

How can I get only the `Ext.form.field.TextField` instances?

Comment: ExtJS ComboBox extends Ext.form.field.Text, so has no nested textfields. Actually it is an upgraded textfield itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need call the function getXType().

Extjs documentation http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getXType

Example

```
var t = new Ext.form.field.Text();

alert(t.getXType());  // alerts 'textfield'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this form of query causes the `Ext.ComponentQuery` to lookup if the current component either is a `textfield` or extend from `textfield`. Simply use a property query for such a case like `[xtype=textfield]`. Is doesn'T matter if you create the `textfield` without setting the `xtype` or creating it by it's `xtype` it be set on the instance.

Here's example will return two results.

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Contact Info',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text',{
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
    }), {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'email',
        fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
        vtype: 'email'  // requires value to be a valid email address format
    }]
});
console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[xtype=textfield]', form));
```